# pixi.js: Stop Rotate when click on sprite?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I want to **stop rotate** when click on [Sprite Image](http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=basics&f=basic.js&title=Basics). How could I do this? I want to click that Bunny and have it stop rotating, and when i click it again ,it will start rotating again. Thank you.

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 300, { backgroundColor: 0x1099bb });
$("#container").append(renderer.view);
var stage = new PIXI.Container();

var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("/Content/img/bunny.png");
var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;
bunny.position.x = 200;
bunny.position.y = 150;

stage.addChild(bunny);

animate();

function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    bunny.rotation += 0.1;

    renderer.render(stage);
}

function onClick(eventData)
{

}
```

> I Updated my Code ,the click event can work now,but how to unbind **onclick** event?

```
var bunny = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("/Content/img/bunny.png");
//var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;
bunny.position.x = 200;
bunny.position.y = 150;
bunny.interactive = true;

bunny.on("click", onClick);
stage.addChild(bunny);

renderImage();

function renderImage()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(renderImage);
    renderer.render(stage);
}

function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    bunny.rotation += 0.1;
    renderer.render(stage);

}

function onClick(eventData)
{
    //animate()
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```

Comment: If you just want to remove the onClick function you can use document.getElementById("idofelement").removeEventListener("click",onClick);.

Comment: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/381 i believe you are facing same issue.
When you done the click event you can make toggle variable to play and pause rotation instead of removing the even as this won't make event fire next time plus stopping request animation is not good option what if there are other animation you want simple is:
function onClick(){ rotateBunny = !rotateBunny}
var rotateBunny = true;
function animate(){ requestAnimationframe(animate) (rotateBunny) ? //rotation logic : null}

Answer (score 0):

It looks likes you need an on click event for your code. So if possible give the element your want to click on an id.

If the pixi library already assigns an id? Try right clicking on the element in the browser and then click inspect element and see if you can find an id.

Once you have an id for the element then create an event listener for the document since I am assuming that the element you want to click on is created after the page is loaded.

js code:

```
//add the event listener
document.addEventListener("click",function(event){//begin event listener


/*
if the event target id equals the id of the element you want to click on
and the animation is running
*/
if(event.target.id === "idofyourelement" && isRunning()){//begin if then


   //call the function to stop your animation here

}//end if then

/*
if the event target id equals the id of the element you want to click on
and the animation is not running
*/
if(event.target.id === "idofyourelement" && !isRunning()){//begin if then


   //call the function to start your animation here

}//end if then




});//end event listener

function isRunning(){

/*
place your to check if the animation is running in here 
hint have it return true if it is running and return false if 
it is not running
*/   

if(condition to check it is running){//begin if then

    return true;

}
else{

    return false;

}//end if then else
```

Now You will have to do a little work to wire up the functions specific to the library you are using but hopefully this will give you a good start.

Comment: @Lany Lane Thanks Guy,but pixi.js is based on **Canvas**,so I can not do as you wrote.But I found a not very good solution.see my reply.

Comment: If it works for you, why is not a very good solution.  What does it not do that you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

> I Found this way can **work**.

```
 var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 300, { backgroundColor: 0x1099bb });
$("#container").append(renderer.view);
var stage = new PIXI.Container();

var bunny = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("/Content/img/bunny.png");
//var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;
bunny.position.x = 200;
bunny.position.y = 150;
bunny.interactive = true;

bunny.on("click", onClick);
stage.addChild(bunny);

renderImage();

function renderImage()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(renderImage);
    renderer.render(stage);
}

function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        bunny.rotation += 0.1;


    renderer.render(stage);

}

function animateErase()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animateErase);
    bunny.rotation -=0.1;
    renderer.render(stage);
}


function onClick(eventData)
{



    if (bunny.rotation ==0) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    else if (bunny.rotation > 0) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animateErase);
    }

    else {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a bunch of different rendering functions. Just set a boolean property on the bunny object and switch it's value in the click listener.

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 300, { backgroundColor: 0x1099bb });
$("#container").append(renderer.view);
var stage = new PIXI.Container();

var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("/Content/img/bunny.png");
var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;
bunny.position.x = 200;
bunny.position.y = 150;

stage.addChild(bunny);

//Boolean property allows bunny to rotate
bunny.canRotate = true;

//Click listener turns on/off rotate property
bunny.on("click", function() {
  this.canRotate = !this.canRotate;
});

// start animating
animate();
function animate() {
    if(bunny.canRotate)
        bunny.rotation += 0.1;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```